# iTerm2 shortcut key to get the last word of the previous command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, gnome-terminal

In GNOME terminal **ALT + .** will give you the last word of the previous command. This functionality was really helpful but i have recently switched to iTerm2 and could not find how to achive this.

is there any shortcut key in iTerm2 to achive this functionality? if not, how to configure iTerm2 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in iTerm2 is `Esc + .`